# firefox + chrome extension: bring new window on top (foreground) - windows 10

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to do the following, on user interaction/event (user copies a word), the extension opens a new window and sends to a specific URL (containing that word). This window opens focused by default. This works fine as long as the user copies the word from a web page, the new window is visible and on top of the current browser window.

The problem is, when someone is copying a word from a text editor: The window opens (default focused) but doesn't come in the foreground (i.e. **above** the current window in which the text was copied). I want the new created window to come on top of whatever application the user copied the word from.

By searching the mozilla developer forums, there seems to be an `alwaysOnTop` property which is `false`. Trying to set that value to true, during the window creation triggers an error. Setting it to true after the creation does nothing.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: it seems to not work only in Windows 10. It works alright (window automatically in foreground) in Windows 7